# nrf51 timer driver code bugs

Tags: c, keil, nrf51

I'm currently trying to make an application  using the nrf51 development kit & I'm trying to use the timer driver, when I induled the C & H files of the driver I got some error :

```
static const nrf_drv_timer_config_t m_default_config[] = {// here it told me there is error #1
 #if (TIMER0_ENABLED == 1)
NRF_DRV_TIMER_DEFAULT_CONFIG(0),
#endif
#if (TIMER1_ENABLED == 1)
NRF_DRV_TIMER_DEFAULT_CONFIG(1),
#endif
#if (TIMER2_ENABLED == 1)
NRF_DRV_TIMER_DEFAULT_CONFIG(2)
#endif
};

// here it told me there is error #2

ret_code_t nrf_drv_timer_init(nrf_drv_timer_t const * const p_instance,
                          nrf_drv_timer_config_t const * p_config,
                          nrf_timer_event_handler_t timer_event_handler)
{
ASSERT((p_instance->instance_id) < TIMER_INSTANCE_NUMBER);
ASSERT(TIMER_IS_BIT_WIDTH_VALID(p_instance->instance_id, p_config->bit_width));

if (m_cb[p_instance->instance_id].state != NRF_DRV_STATE_UNINITIALIZED)
{
    return NRF_ERROR_INVALID_STATE; // timer already initialized
} 

if (p_config == NULL)
{
    p_config = &m_default_config[p_instance->instance_id];
}

#ifdef SOFTDEVICE_PRESENT
if (p_instance->p_reg == NRF_TIMER0)
{
    return NRF_ERROR_INVALID_PARAM;
}
#endif    

nrf_drv_common_irq_enable(p_instance->irq, p_config->interrupt_priority);

mp_contexts[p_instance->instance_id] = p_config->p_context;

if (timer_event_handler != NULL)
{
    m_timer_event_handlers[p_instance->instance_id] = timer_event_handler;
}
else
{
    return NRF_ERROR_INVALID_PARAM;
}

nrf_timer_mode_set(p_instance->p_reg, p_config->mode);
nrf_timer_bit_width_set(p_instance->p_reg, p_config->bit_width);
nrf_timer_frequency_set(p_instance->p_reg, p_config->frequency);

m_cb[p_instance->instance_id].state = NRF_DRV_STATE_INITIALIZED;

return NRF_SUCCESS;
}
```

the error #1 says that "an empty initializer is invalid for an array with unspecified bound"
the error #2 says that it expected an expression

I till now didn't use any of these functions in the main.c code, I'm just added the header files that will be used further.

Answer (score 1):

Error 1: Apparently neither of `TIMERx_ENABLED` is 1, so the array will be empty. As it is `const`, there is no chance to initialize it later. That would also result in an array of zero elements, which is not allowed. Easiest might be to have an `#else` clause with a single null entry. However, I suspect you have to configure the stuff for your system first. Read the documentation.

Error 2: might be a follow up error, or one of the custom types are not defined - hard to say without more info, or the location the error is reported is simply not that of the actual error, or ... . Best is to fix the first error, then try again for error 2.

Comment: I'll try to initialize them in the main.c code and then see if it's fixed or not.. thanks for your help

Comment: Just again: you cannot initialize `const` other than when you define it. However, remeber to upvote/accept if that helps/was the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using examples from nordic then the defines are either in nrf_drv_config.h or in the sdk_config.h for new versions of the nordic sdk.

You have to enable the timers by changing the TIMER_ENABLED define to 1. Then do the same for the timers you want to use.

You could make these defines yourself as other people have suggested.